# Global Average Pooling layer and location information

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, pooling

I've got a question about the usage of Global Average Pooling layer (GAP).
I am working on the classification of sea level pressure data, where obviously the location of high/low pressure system matters.
The [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.4400.pdf) on GAP states:

> Furthermore, global average pooling sums out the spatial information, thus it is more robust to spatial translations of the input

Similarly, [another paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11042-021-11435-5) states:

> At the end of the network, Global Average Pooling is used to instead of a Fully Connected layer. Compared with a Fully Connected layer, Global Average Pooling will dilute the combination of the
> relative positions of different features.

My current CNN has the following setup:
[Several convolutional and max pooling layers] -> Global average pooling layer -> dense layer -> output

I am surprised that this gives me my best classification results. According to those papers spatial information is lost in the process. My conclusion would be that this should make my results worse or even unusable, because in my case spatial local information matters. What could be the reason that I am getting my best results with that setup?